# Apple Script + VPN + Textbox

Tags: applescript, password, vpn, text-input

I have an applescript :

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set VPNService to service "VPN (Cisco IPSec)"
        if exists VPNService then
            connect VPNService
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

When I execute it a dialog box is showing up and ask me for my password. I would like to automate this process and put directly my password in my script and validate automatically the dialog box.

Is there a way a to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set VPNService to service "UJF"
        if exists VPNService then
            connect VPNService
        end if
    end tell
    delay 1
    keystroke "yourpassword"
end tell
```

If 1 second delay isn't enough for the popop to open feel free to increase it !

But don't forget, a password *should* NEVER be stored like that.